# Jitsi Meet screen sharing works not with a single monitor only with all monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde, kubuntu, jitsi

I using KUbuntu its probably using Plasma that's using Wayland.

An Jitsi - Meet screen sharing here now allows not sharing a single monitor screen, because i using two. it shares only two.

For about a year i was able to select a single monitor screen.

Somebody today told me it works for him if he using x11-Desktop.

What i need to do for using Jitsi screen sharing with only a single monitor? Do i need to try switch from Wayland to x11-Desktop?

## i have read:

seems a problem for many users:

https://community.jitsi.org/t/select-which-monitor-to-share/24292/4

here i found a workaround, but not works here in my OS.
share second screen (create window that captures the contents of second display)
laptop screen width: 1366 (second screen starts on the right of that, see xrandr or display settings)
second screen resolution: 1920x1080

put ffplay window in background, do not minimize
then select the appropriate window from the dropdown list in Firefox browser
https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/issues/2894

here is the idea to install a virtual camera:

https://community.jitsi.org/t/screen-sharing-with-dual-head-monitor-setup/34787/2

## System Infos:

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me. Just using chromium-browser, not with Firefox.

`sudo apt install chromium-browser`
... Installing the chromium snap

Tested by starting **chromium** then at **https://meet.jit.si**

in firefox it still doesn't work. (only entire screen, i.e. all monitors)

TimeStamp: 2021-0811_0557-06